# Как отменить действие класса navbar-fixed-top на мобильном разрешении?

Tags: javascript, css

```
#navbarlol {
    z-index: 9999;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#navbarlol a {
    display: block;
}


var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
    var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;

    if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
        document.getElementById("navbarlol").style.top = "0px";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("navbarlol").style.top = "-45px";
    }

    prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

и ещё может подскажите по скрипту после перезагрузки когда начинаешь скролить резко скачок в верх на 45 пикселей, а как сделать скачок в плавное действие?

Comment: а где, собственно, этот класс `navbar-fixed-top`?)

Comment: этот класс в шапке <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse-night"> дальше там много кода идёт

Comment: прошу прощения, но как можно пытаться **отменить действие класса**, если *мы* даже не знаем что это за класс и что он делает? Вы со мной согласны, что Ваш вопрос не полностью раскрыт?

Comment: это класс бутстрап 3, может быть с помощью js его удалить можно при разрешении например < 991

Comment: всё равно не понятно, но интуитивно я догадываюсь чего Вы ожидаете. Вы хотите, что бы на мобильной версии Ваш обработчик событий `window.onscroll` не скрывал блок `navbarlol` (то есть, не срабатывало событие)?

Comment: @Август я хочу чтобы класс navbar-fixed-top был на всех разрешениях больше 991px, а на разрешениях меньше 991 этот класс удалялся. Мне надо чтобы на ПК меню сайта было закреплено при скроле, а на мобильнике чтобы срабатывал скрипт, представленный в вопросе, этому мешает класс navbar-fixed-top

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105183/discussion-between-alexfixer-and-).

Answer (score 0):

Есть метод такой

```
domElement.scrollBy({
 top: 0, // сколл по вертикали
 left: offset, // сколл по горизонтали
 behavior: 'smooth' // это говорит о том, что надо скролить плавно
});
```

Попробуй. Может оно? А про первый вопрос не очень понятно. Вроде это медиазапросами решается.

Comment: только автор поста, **скорее всего**, хотел чтобы блок `#navbarlol` просто плавно скрывался/открывался

Answer (score 0):

ответ дан отталкиваясь от дискуссии в комментариях:

> поведение класса `navbar-fixed-top`

всё, что касается стилей (как будет вести себя класс, учитывая размер экрана) - решаться должно в стилях с помощью **медиа запросов**. то есть, не обязательно удалять класс `navbar-fixed-top`, если размер устройства меньше **991px**.

если с **медиа запросами** проблемы, то удаляйте класс `navbar-fixed-top` при загрузке страницы. например, так:

```
document.addEventListener('load', () => {
    if (window.innerWidth < 991) {
        document.querySelector('navbar').classList.remove('navbar-fixed-top');
    }
});
```

но учтите, что при изменении ширины экрана, класс сам не вернется, по-этому нужно это учесть и добавить событие `resize`.

так же обратите внимание, что Ваше событие `window.onscroll` будет работать всегда, а для *десктопной версии* Вам это не нужно. при загрузке страницы нужно (!) учесть этот момент. например:

```
document.addEventListener('load', () => {
    if (window.innerWidth < 991) {
        window.onscroll = function() {
            .... //Ваш код по скрытию/появлению блока navbar
```

> как сделать плавное **скрытие**/**появление** `#navbarlol`

добавить блоку `#navbarlol` стиль `transition: top 1s;`

> несколько замечаний

учтите, что если Вы навешиваете обработчики событий как свойство (`window.onscroll` и т.д), то таким образом Вы можете вешать только по одному виду событий на элемент. например, следующий `window.onscroll` перепишет предыдущий `window.onscroll`. используйте как альтернативу `addEventListener`.